# cusolver library not found

Tags: python, cuda, scikits

I am trying to use skcuda in my python code but whenever i want to use it, it rises the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/rohola/Projects/Python/wordnetwork/s.py", line 6, in     <module>
from skcuda import cusolver
File "/home/rohola/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-     packages/skcuda/cusolver.py", line 51, in <module>
raise OSError('cusolver library not found')
OSError: cusolver library not found
```

i was just tried to use skcuda

```
from skcuda import cusolver
handle = cusolver.cusolverDnCreate()
```

i installed pycuda, NVIDIA CUDA Toolkit. What's wrong about my code or dependencies?

Comment: Which version of CUDA are you using?

Comment: my cuda version is cuda-7.5

Comment: with correct environment setup such as LD_LIBRARY_PATH ? http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions

Comment: Yes, i set that for the first use.

Comment: I am a little confused but i didn't install BLAS and LAPACK which is used for linear algebra for gpu computing. Is that even relevant?

Comment: All dependencies? http://scikit-cuda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Comment: Yes, i have installed all dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my problem. Firstly, i searched for libcusolver.so with

```
locate libcusolver.so
```

and then changed the following code in cusolver.py from:

```
_libcusolver = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(_libcusolver_libname)
```

to:

```
_libcusolver = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("/usr/local/cuda-7.5/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/"+_libcusolver_libname)
```

now the following code:

```
from skcuda import cusolver
handle = cusolver.cusolverDnCreate()
```

works without any error.

UPDATE:

If you have installed cuda8.0 or 9.0 the best way to solve the problem is to find this line in cusolver.py:

```
_libcusolver = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(_libcusolver_libname)
```

and add this line before it:
     ctypes.CDLL('libgomp.so.1', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)

You have to make sure that you already installed libgomp.

Comment: In addition to this, you might need to add something like <ctypes.CDLL('/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1', mode=ctypes.RTLD_GLOBAL)> prior to importing libcusolver. This issue has been posted here - https://github.com/lebedov/scikit-cuda/issues/171

Answer (score 3):

```
import ctypes
a = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary( "/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so" )
```

gets me

```
OSError: /usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcusolver.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_critical_end
```

which seems to be a yet unsolved issue according to [this github thread](https://github.com/lebedov/scikit-cuda/issues/171)

Though, a 7.5 version which

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcusolver.so
```

seems to point to works well. And author's fix seems to work with it.